# Drag and drop within RecyclerView

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, android-5.0-lollipop

I would like to have drag and drop feature (for reordering) within an Android L version RecyclerView.

I assume this widget doesn't provide this feature itself, right?
In that case, how to implement such feature?

Comment: Pretty much the same way you would do it with a listview: www.youtube.com/watch?v=_BZIvjMgH-Q Start by copying their implementation and you will find there are only a few small differences

Comment: Trying to do as stated tough it proved tougher than I predicted. I will post code when I get the hang of it.

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas on this ? I haven't seen any tutorials or how-to's. If anyone has some idea how to accomplish please say something as I'm about to go back to listviews for the items I need to drag and drop.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener.html seems to be a good point to start.

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/helper/ItemTouchHelper.html