# Order elements of a RecyclerView via drag and drop

Tags: android, sorting, drag-and-drop, android-recyclerview

I am developing an application for Android which is a `RecyclerView` containing `LinearLayout` through a list of custom items. How can you order these items using drag and drop?

Comment: Would you use ListView instead? A related post in SO is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24789220/drag-and-drop-within-recyclerview?rq=1

Comment: no, I have to use recyclerview.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Drag and drop items in RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29901044/drag-and-drop-items-in-recyclerview-with-gridlayoutmanager)

Comment: xamarin android example http://www.appliedcodelog.com/2019/08/reorder-list-items-by-drag-and-drop-in.html